# Почему в консоль выводит NaN?

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener

```js
class GODListener {
  constructor() {
    this.counter = 0;
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.counter += 1;
    console.log(this.counter);
  }
}

const element = document.getElementById('testBtn');
const listener = new GODListener();

element.addEventListener("click", listener.handleClick);
```

```html
<button id='testBtn'>Тест</button>
```

Comment: потому что подписка без контекста: element.addEventListener("click", listener.handleClick.bind(listener));

Comment: 1) ```this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)``` или 2) стрелочная функция ```handleClick = () => { code }```. Пример https://jsfiddle.net/0x13hwft/